# What to do when a button click work for some datasets and not for others?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a page where users can work with their data. The page has 2 gridviews. Initially, the top grid display records that can be selected with a "check box" column and added to the other gridview with Add/remove buttons.

This works well and has worked well for years. Suddenly, now, for some datasets, clicking the button does not seem to trigger the button click event. This work for others datasets. I know this is probably a specific situation but any comment would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance
B

Comment: This pages has 600 lines of code and you probably won't have time to study it. To make sense of it would also require to post all the dependent code. A big help would be to know where one should look when the breakpoint in pageload is not hit unexpectedly?

Comment: And as i said, this click event is fired when o load a different dataset. No excepetion is thrown when it does not fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that its only happening for some datasets I would suggest that its the data which is causing the problem.

check you don't have duplicate Ids

check you don't have special characters (ms word single quotes, £,# etc)

also sometimes users don't click hard enough. check they are clicking hard

Comment: duplicate keys was the problem